# Group .ui files in project tree when using CMake

Tags: c++, qt, cmake, qt-creator

I have a simple gui project in QtCreator, which consists of several .cpp .h and .ui files and using CMake as a build system.

The problem i face is that .ui files, as oposed to .cpp and .h files, aren't grouped under corresponding header in project tree. They are just shown on the same level as .cpp and .h headers (see picture below).

[image]

I had no such problem when i was using qmake as a build system. I can totally live with that, but it can get really annoying as the project grows. Is there a way in QtCreator to customize appearance of a project tree?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `source_group` in your CMakeLists.txt to group `*.ui` files as a source group in QtCreator or another IDE

```
file(GLOB_RECURSE UI_SRC "*.ui")
source_group("Ui Files" FILES ${UI_SRC})
```

This also works for .qml files for example.